# node.js express 4.13.3 serveStatic not serving mp3 or ogg files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mp3, ogg

I'm using Express 4.13.3  and the serve-static npm library. It serves static assets fine EXCEPT those with mp3 or ogg extensions.  Looking at the documentation I haven't found anything to indicate that this is configurable, and others appear to be loading audio and video without issues with earlier express.

The directory is simple:

```
/public/assets/image.jpg  **works ok**
/public/assets/audio.mp3  404?!
/public/assets/audio.ogg  404?!
```

The code is simple:

```
 app = express();
 app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public'));
 app.use('/', router);
```

I can use node.js to return files but that seems a poor choice given the number of audio files.  Any idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: did you put `/public` in your url by any chance?

Comment: @hassansin /public isn't needed to load the jpg in the same folder, but even with /public in the name it's not working.

Comment: Right, /public isn't needed, but since it's 404, I thought you put /public in url.

Answer (score 0):

Doh, it's was actually a load balancer in front of the node server not recognizing the static file extension, so adding the 2 .mp3 and .ogg to haproxy's configuration fixed it.

```
  acl url_static    path_end    -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js .html .ico  .mp3 .ogg
```